# Loading of GDAL library impossible after an upgrade

Tags: python, django, homebrew, gdal

I have a Python environment with Django 3 that has to use GDAL (because the DB engine I use is `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`). After an upgrade of GDAL (from 3.6.4_6 to 3.7.1_1), I have this exception on any command to run the django project :

```
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3Aws6Client19ClientConfigurationC1Ev
  Referenced from: <FA8C3295-2793-3C69-A419-16C41753696B> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-arrow/12.0.1_4/lib/libarrow.1200.1.0.dylib
  Expected in:     <BDB1F1E3-0BE9-3D7D-A57E-9D9F8CAD197A> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sdk-cpp/1.11.145/lib/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.dylib
```

I've managed to isolate the problem in a fresh python environment with only loading the GDAL library : `from ctypes import CDLL; CDLL("/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib")`.

Note, I'm on a Mac (CPU M2 Pro), I've installed GDAL and all its dependancies via brew. I've tried reinstalling it from fresh but it didn't change a thing and I've also tried with different python versions.

**Aftermatch:** An issue was opened soon after my post ([#140082](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/140082)) and the pull request ([!140127](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/140127)) fixing it was merged on the 22nd of August 2023. So you just need to do `brew update && brew upgrade`

Comment: Did you installed this dependency `sudo apt-get install --yes libgdal-dev` and `sudo apt-get -y install gdal-bin`

Comment: @Ahtisham Since it's on macOS, dependancies aren't managed via apt-get but via brew. The dependancies are fully installed (and were fully functional until I updated them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same `OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3Aws6Client19ClientConfigurationC1Ev` . Applied the approach suggested by @bennylope (https://nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages/) and got it worked:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/824c551b4f514e7cd86358133924906b982c87e2/Formula/postgis.rb 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0faa586d8415cd2ced33345aa3e13c664c92aeda/Formula/a/aws-sdk-cpp.rb
brew install postgis.rb
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies aws-sdk-cpp
brew install aws-sdk-cpp.rb
brew link aws-sdk-cpp
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I don't know why when I reinstalled gdal and some other dependancies but without success. But with your instructions I managed to get it working (just in my case the `brew link aws-sdk-cpp` was unnecessary, and I had to `brew unlink postgis` before its installation from the file and relink it after the whole thing `brew link postgis`). Anyway, thanks again, I can work with my project again. And I noticed you just created your account (I don't know if it was to answer me) and this is the first answer you posted, I'm just so glad you did, you rock

Comment: You're welcome! I spent hours resolving this occasion. My goal was to save people the stress and time of going through the same silly problem. Don't want anyone else pulling their hair out over this - especially when the clock's ticking and you're on a deadline.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for but maybe it will help, because I just faced the exact same issue on my Mac M1, right down to the mangled name of the symbol that could not be found (`__ZN3Aws6Client19ClientConfigurationC1Ev`).

I wrestled with this for about an hour, trying to get the latest version to work, and also trying to get Homebrew to install the older version that *did* work.  I finally ended up restoring my entire `/opt/homebrew` directory (parent of the `Cellar` directory) from yesterday's Time Machine backup.  I can now run my Django application again, albeit with the older gdal (in my case, `3.6.4_7`).

Comment: Thanks, sadly I don't have Time Machine setup right now (I removed it from my NAS few months ago to retrieve space for some other things and I'll set it up back in few months). So at least your story tells me I'm not the only one facing this issue, and I guess that like me you never found a single result on the web with that problematic symbol. Also like you, I tried to install older version of the formulae, without any success either …

Comment: You might *try* removing the packages and then reinstalling the older version using a strategy [like this one](https://nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages/). Frankly it did not work for me; instead what did work was finally trying [nix](https://zero-to-nix.com/) (!!!) to install `gdal` because I'm tired of `brew upgrade` breaking things.

Comment: @bennylope si basically you removed the gdal formulae from brew and you used an other package system to install it ? I don’t know about nix but it could be a good solution (and I totally agree about the problems with environments using dependencies from brew, it’s a nightmare)

Comment: @FlorentinLeMoal while I did uninstall `gdal`, it wouldn't be necessary, because you can choose the path to use in your Django settings using [`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdallibrarypath). So mine uses the `nix` install path to `libgdal.dylib`, and this *does* work now. That being said unless you wanted to experiment or work with `nix` in some other way, it would likely be overkill just to solve this one problem. It might be simpler to try installing from the `GDAL` source using the exact version you want.

Comment: Well thanks to @Charlie's solution I've got it working again with brew, and I'll make sure to `brew pin` my dependancies (and setup back my Time Machine network disk as fast as possible). But I'm gooing to look this nix solution, because it appears to be pretty cool way to define a dev environnement (on my project we use docker for the other devs, but I prefer to run it directly on my OS).

Comment: By the way, should we open an issue on the homebrew repo? Because we're apparently many with the same problem, so there might be a issue with one of the latest builds

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your libgeos and libgdal paths have changed due to an upgrade. e.g. I was able to fix the issue by editing `settings.py`:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.7.1_1/lib/libgdal.dylib'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.12.0/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

to

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.8.2/lib/libgdal.dylib'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.12.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

thanks @bennylope!